# Drag and Drop images from menu to page

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, draggable

I am having a bit of trouble with finding a tutorial or examples on how I can do the following:

I have a list menu of images and what I am trying to achieve is, a user can drag a copy of the image from the list menu onto the body of a website and then be able to move the image around anywhere on the page.

I hope this makes sense?!

I found a website that achieves this, however I am new to jquery and when I have looked at the source code for inspiration it wasn't very clear how they have achieved it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at Jquery UI? http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

Answer (score 0):

You can jquery ui plugin to achieve it easily.

Look following links :

http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable

http://www.ericbieller.com/2010/06/24/how-to-create-a-simple-drag-and-drop-with-jquery/